# Flutter: SliverAppBar with TabBar and persistent header

Tags: flutter

I've been looking for a way to make the following layout scroll correctly in Flutter:

[image: Layout]

When scrolling, the `AppBar` should first contract, leaving only the `TabBar` visible. Then, the Top widget should scroll, leaving the Header widget pinned at the top, below the `TabBar`. Finally, the `TabBarView` should scroll.

How would I do this in Flutter, using Material 3?

The `AppBar` and `TabBar` is scrolling correctly using a `NestedScrollView`. I can't figure out how to get the body to scroll correctly though.

My current layout:

```dart
Scaffold(
  body: DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return [
          const SliverAppBar(
            title: Text("AppBar"),
            floating: true,
            pinned: true,
            bottom: TabBar(tabs: [
              Tab(text: "Tab 1"),
              Tab(text: "Tab 2"),
            ]),
          )
        ];
      },
      body: Column(children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          child: Center(child: Text("Top widget")),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(child: Text("Header widget")),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(children: [
            Center(child: Text("Tab 1")),
            Center(child: Text("Tab 2")),
          ]),
        ),
      ]),
    ),
  ),
),
```